# Collision between player and enemy not working

Tags: java

I am making a game in Java. And the collision between player and enemy is not working right.

What I want: when they collide, it's Game Over and we need to go to the Game Over Panel. 
What it does instead: the enemy runs over the player and the game just goes on.

I copy pasted a piece of my code and I really hope someone can find what I am doing wrong.

For further information, the player and enemies can should bullets to each other and that collision works. There are also obstacles placed randomly, which both player and enemy detect.

What do to when player collides with an enemy:

```
for(Enemy enemy: enemies){
if (checkCollision(player, enemy)){
    player.dead = true;
    }
}
```

I update the player in the action performed function:

```
if (!player.dead)
            player.redraw();

else
{
    spelTimer.stop();
    mainVenster.switchPanel(new GameOverPanel(mainVenster));}
```

Function checkCollision (idk if this can be helpful):

```
public boolean checkCollision(tanks.Game_Object object1, tanks.Game_Object object2){

    double dx = object1.x_pos - object2.x_pos;
    double dy = object1.y_pos - object2.y_pos;
    double distance = (dx*dx) + (dy*dy);
    double minDistance = (object1.r+object2.r);

    return (distance < minDistance*minDistance);    
}
```

EDIT: The x_pos and y_pos are the center coordinates of my objects and r is the radius.

Comment: It's possible your frame rate isn't high enough and even though the bullet *looks* like it's intersecting the player, the program only sees the frame before and the frame after. You might want to try increasing the threshold minDistance to something twice as big and see how things work.

Comment: how did you update coordinates?

Comment: @bcr I'm going to try and see what that gives. I must say though, when I (the player) shoot at enemies or obstacles (and I hit them), they get removed.

Comment: @haifzhan I set a public Timer timer at a delay of 50ms. I hope this is what you wanted to know?

Answer (score 1):

Your player and enemies are represented by circles, right? That's what it seems like from your code. In that case, the correct collision formula is:

```
double dist = Math.sqrt(Math.sqr(obj1.x + ob1.radius - obj2.x - obj2.radius) + Math.sqr(obj1.y + ob1.radius - obj2.y - obj2.radius));

if (dist < (obj1.radius + obj2.radius)) {
  //collision
}
```

Comment: Yes, I tried working with rectangles before, but it gave me difficulties since both the player and enemy can translate and rotate (they are 'tanks'). I looked at what you said and it looks pretty much the same as my checkCollision function (my x_pos and y_pos are the center coordinated of my objects)?

Comment: You should have to mention it that your pivot is at the center of your drawings at the first place :)

Answer (score 0):

May be

```
public boolean checkCollision(tanks.Game_Object object1, tanks.Game_Object object2){

    double dx = object1.x_pos - object2.x_pos;
    double dy = object1.y_pos - object2.y_pos;
    double distance = (dx*dx) + (dy*dy);
    double minDistance = (object1.r+object2.r);

    return (Math.sqrt(distance) < minDistance);    
}
```

Comment: You're calculating from the top left. You need to calculate from the center of the circle

Comment: I don't think the adding a sqrt() will do the trick, but I am going to try! And @ControlAltDel isn't this code right, if you see the x_pos and y_pos as the center coordinates?

Comment: @ml20 It might not do the trick. But he DOES point out a flaw that nobody noticed, it seems. a^2 + b^2 = c^2. You're distance isn't calculated correctly, you need to get the square root of c, which in your case is `distance`. This is definitely an important step in fixing the problem if it doesn't fix it.

Comment: @NicholasEason Instead of adding the square root to the left side of the inequality I added a square to the right side. ((dx*dx) + (dy*dy) < minDistance*minDistance)

Answer (score 0):

For this situation, I would recommend a `Rectangle`. When you create a `Rectangle` you tell it the top-left point, then how far it extends in each direction (Like you're trying to figure out in your method). You then just have to update the `Rectangle` with the player (using `rectangle.reshape(x,y,width,height)`) , and everywhere you currently check collision, check the player's `Rectangle` over the Enemy's `Rectangle` with the collision method.

```
Rectangle r = new Rectangle(x,y,100,100);
Rectangle q = new Rectangle(x2,y2,100,100);
if(r.intersects(q)){
    //What occurs during collision
}
```

Comment: It is not optimal to abstract shape collision away like this

Comment: @ControlAltDel Yeah, it makes sense that it's a circle looking at it... I dont know why I didn't think about it before but if they 100% really are circles, then this isn't the way to do it. However, this will still work if they are.

Comment: Well, this was the first thing I tried, but it gave me difficulties with what to do when two objects did collide, since my player and enemies can translate and rotate.

Comment: That's why you use `Rectangle.reshape(x,y,width,height)` make a method for it called `udpdatePlayer(int x, int y)` or something like that and make it update the player's rectangle location. However since these are circles, see ControlAltDel's answer since it's better for this situation.

Answer (score -2):

Actually the best way to modelize collisions in a game on java is to draw 4 hit boxes :
A very thin rectangle in top, bottom, left, right of your character.
An then if one of the hit boxes of the enemy contains on of the hitboxes of the player (une the intersects method), you will know that there has been a collision, and even better, you wil know the side of the collision.

more info:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mdJNtXP1QiY

Comment: Wouldn't drawing 4 boxes around the character be just as effective as 1 larger box containing the player?

Comment: Not at all !! If there was one hit box and we supose the top left corner intersects with one hit box of the enemy, will the collision be top or left ? That's why it is  better to separate them. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mdJNtXP1QiY

Comment: But with that logic I could argue that storing every point of every pixel is the best way to go about this even though in the end the player immediately dies, at least we'll know exactly where the intersection was... Although I do see where you're going, it's just that in this situation it's not as important.

Comment: But what if the player only dies when the collision is either top, left, right. Look at the youtube vi i posted and you'll have and idea about it. It is nit necessary to worry about each pixel.

Comment: But you could easily find a situation where you could argue that it's necessary to worry about each pixel. Maybe you want a perfect hit box. Maybe you want the death animation to have some sort of exact directional based animation. i.e if a person is shot from 45 degrees above and you want a perfectly angled blood splatter. You'd have to know the point of entry and point of exit which aren't going to get told to you via directional locations.